# Why can't I display my items in Flatlist?

Tags: json, react-native

I am currently trying to learn React-Native atm and I am having some trouble displaying out my items in my FlatList.

The below is my code

```
import React from 'react';
import { FlatList, ActivityIndicator, Text, View  } from 'react-native';

export default class FetchExample extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      dataSource: []
    }
}

  componentDidMount(){

    return fetch('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
           .then((res) => res.json())
           .then((resJson) => {
           console.log('Here are the stuff', resJson.bpi)
           this.setState({
              isLoading: false,
              dataSource: resJson.bpi,
             })
           })
// catch any potential errors here
    .catch((error) =>{
      console.log(error)
    })
  }

  render(){
if(this.state.isLoading){
  return(
    <View style={{flex: 1, padding: 20}}>
      <ActivityIndicator />
    </View>
  );
}
return(
  <View style={{flex: 0.5, padding: 20}}>
    <Text>{console.log(this.state.dataSource)}</Text>
    <Text>Here's some testing text</Text>
    <Text>{console.log("This is in this.state.dataSource", this.state.dataSource)}</Text>
    {/* <FlatList 
      data= {this.state.dataSource}
      renderItem = {({item}) => <Text>{console.log(item)}</Text>} 
      /> */}
  </View>
)
  }
}
```

Whenever I uncomment the FlatList the simulator will shoot me an error saying "Invariant Violation: Tried to get frame for out of range index NaN"

What am I doing wrong? Atm I am just trying to see what's in item and get an understanding of how to work with Flatlist

Comment: why do you put console.log inside Text ?

Comment: If you want to put `console.log`, you should put it before `return`

Comment: @liupluto it's temporarily there for me to see what's in item. But even when I do <Text>{item}</Text> I still get an error

Comment: @john doe can you try `item.USD.code` and see what is the output ?

Comment: @AravindS Yeah just did that and still got the same error as mentioned in the question

Comment: @JohnDoe can you change the data to `this.state.dataSource.USD` and console `item.code`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here how i do it

```js
 <FlatList
          data={[this.state.dataSource]}
          renderItem={({ item }) => this._renderListItem(item)}
        />
```

and here the _renderListItem()

```js
 _renderListItem(item){
    console.log(item)
      return(
        <View>
          <View style={{flexDirection:'row',width:'100%',backgroundColor:'red'}}>
          <Text>{item.USD.code}</Text>
          <Text>{item.USD.symbol}</Text>
          <Text>{item.USD.description}</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
        )
    }
```

and here is the expo link [click here you get the idea](https://snack.expo.io/r17h8gMMQ)
and if any questions you have please ask me ...

Comment: this worked like a charm and so easy to understand. Thank you!